# How to disable right click on youtube embed IFRAME?

Tags: youtube, embed, youtube-iframe-api

I am placing a youtube video on my website. I want to disable the right click so that no one can have an access to the video directly.

Below is the code snippet:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="563" src="' . $yturl . '?controls=' . $controls . '&rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=' . $autoplay . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`
```

Is there any way to achieve this?`

Answer (score 1):

Long time passed since u've asked, i can tell you my experience: i wasted like 1.5h googling around and the best i could find is someone saying to put an invisibile div above the iframe containg the youtube video.
Something easy as

```
<div class="yt-cover"></div>
```

And with a bit of CSS:

```
.yt-cover{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

This should be sufficient. Ofc the parent div MUST have position:relative; to make this work and you have to be able to edit the page HTML/generation in some way.

Anyways i don't know what you were searching that for but if it was for something like what my customer asked: "I don't want people to be able to download the video finding the URL" i can just tell you that if someone REALLY want to download a video from youtube he will eventually find a way, even without being able to right-click and go to url.

Comment: Thanks @Diego It is working indeed but the issue is that even controls are not clickable anymore which is the issue again

Comment: @Himani i gave up trying to disable right click, somehow it looks like a very difficult/impossibile task. I found some more material saying to disable right click on the iframe using the 'contextmenu' (https://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/) event on the iframe to prevent right click but i coudnt make it work properly

Answer (score 0):

My Solution was to disable every thing i have (keyboard key press and mouse right click) and cover 98% the player

full example:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
@php
    $lang = app()->getLocale();
    $dir = config('app.available_locales')[$lang]['dir'] ?? 'ltr';
    $current_page ??= '';
@endphp

<html lang="{{ $lang }}" dir="{{ $dir }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>{{ config('app.name') }}</title>
    <style>
        .video {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 60px;
            max-width: 700px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .video::before {
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            width: 100%;
            height: calc(100% - 51px);
            background-color: transparent;
            z-index: 5;
        }

        .video::after {
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            width: 68px;
            height: 39px;
            background-color: transparent;
            z-index: 5;
            bottom: 4px;
            right: 51px;
        }

        .phone {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            color: white;
            font-size: 26px;
            padding: 4px 6px;
            background-color: #ffffff12;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="video">
    <iframe
        style="width: 100%; height: 500px"
        src="{{ request('url', 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/iu-LBY7NXD4') }}?autoplay=1"
        title="{{ config('app.name') }}"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
    ></iframe>
    <p class="phone">{{ request('watermark', config('app.name')) }}</p>
</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
    document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        return false;
    }
    navigator.keyboard.lock();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```